# Spring parent with 2 child classes use 2 different beans for property

Tags: java, spring, spring-annotations

Say I have the following

```java
public abstract class MyClass {
    @Resource
    protected MyService myService;

    doSomething() {
        return myService.doSomething();
    }
}

public class MyServiceV1 implements MyService {}
public class MyServiceV2 implements MyService {}

public class MyClassV1 extends MyClass {
    //WANT TO USE MyServiceV1 implementation
}

public class MyClassV2 extends MyClass {
    //WANT TO USE MyServiceV2 implementation
}
```

I am unable to specify the service implementation that I want to use in each subclass. I have considered using @Qualifier but I would have to re-declare the property in each child class and use it there, and hope that it overrides the parent.

The purpose of these classes is to provide two versions of an API at the same time. So both versions will be active simultaneously.

It does feel partially that this is an anti pattern in terms of how spring is meant to inject beans, so I am open to other approaches.

Comment: I am not completely sure but it seems what you want to achieve isn't feasible. You want two different implementation but one declaration. There should be some parameter based on which you need to decide. You Either can use Config based on property or based on other bean but If you are using both in same application context then to distinguish you either have to give name e.g. `@Autowired MyService myServiceV1;  @Autowired MyService myServiceV2;  `

Comment: How are you configuring your beans?

Comment: @ChristopherSchneider Annotation component scan (The components have @ Component and @ Controller)

Comment: It is an anti pattern, but not so much because of spring injectinon, but because it shouldn't matter which implementation you use for an interface.

Comment: @daniu but it doesn't? The whole point is that the methods in MyClass use any instance of myService and they don't care which implementation. It is only in the specific myclass implementations that you care about the implementation

Comment: @pasquers so it does, because the specific implementations do care? https://www.tomdalling.com/blog/software-design/solid-class-design-the-liskov-substitution-principle/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can try to use Constructor injection to set a particular service in your classes. Smth like this:

```
public abstract class MyClass {

    protected MyService myService;

    doSomething() {
        return myService.doSomething();
    }
}

class MyClassV1 extends MyClass {
    MyClassV1(MyService myService) {
        this.myService = myService;
    }
}

class MyClassV2 extends MyClass {
    MyClassV2(MyService myService) {
        this.myService = myService;
    }
}

@Bean
MyClassV1 myClassV1() {
    return new MyClassV1(myServiceV1());
}

@Bean
MyClassV1 myClassV2() {
    return new MyClassV2(myServiceV2());
}

@Bean
MyServiceV1 myServiceV1() {
    return new MyServiceV1();
}

@Bean
MyServiceV2 myServiceV2() {
    return new MyServiceV2();
}
```

or setter injection:

```
public abstract class MyClass {

    private MyService myService;

    public void setMyService(MyService myService) {
        this.myService = myService;
    }
}

@Component
public class MyClass1 extends MyClass {
    @Autowired @Qualifier("myService1")
    @Override
    public void setMyService(MyService myService) {
        super.setMyService(myService);
    }
}

@Component
public class MyClass2 extends MyClass {

    @Autowired @Qualifier("myService2")
    @Override
    public void setMyService(MyService myService) {
        super.setMyService(myService);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this would work. We use annotation component scanning though and have no config class at the moment, so I'm not sure how I would accomplish the @Bean declarations without that.

Comment: How about the Setter injection:
```
@Component
class MyClassV1 extends MyClass {
    public void setMyService(@Autowired @Qualifier("myService1") MyService myService) {
  this.myService = myService;
 }
}
```

Comment: sorry, don't know how to fix the text formatting in the comment section

Comment: I will try this today and let you know! I assume that the service declaration in MyClass would have no annotations still right?

Comment: So it looks like the setter injection didn't work, however constructor injection following the same pattern did work. I'm not really sure what the difference is

Comment: @pasquers just tested, works fine, but I forgot that autowired annotation should be above the method, not in the input params, pls find the code in the updated answer